# What controls where an event can be called?

Tags: c#, events

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class FauxIdentityForm
{
    public Guid FormID { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Closed;
    public void TheObjectWasClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Closed(this, e);
    }
}
```

It is fine for me to call the Closed Event inside the `TheObjectWasClosed` method.  But if, in a different class (even in the same file), I have a method like this:

```
public void CallTheEvent()
{
    FauxIdentityForm _formIdentity = new FauxIdentityForm {FormID = Guid.NewGuid()};

    _formIdentity.Closed(_formIdentity, null);  // <-- Does not compile!
}
```

The call to Closed is shot down by the compiler (it wants me to only use += and -=).

So, is actually calling the event only allowed inside the class?  Is that the limitation?

If so, is there anyway around it?  And if not, why did the creators of C# do this?  (It makes working with events very hard sometimes.  I imagine there is a good reason and it is probably saving me from myself, but I would like to know it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's complicated :)

What you're using is called a *field-like event*. When you declare one of those in your class, you're creating a field *and* an event. When you "call the event" you're actually invoking the delegate referred to by the field. As it's a private field, you have access to it within the class (and any nested types), but not outside.

Events themselves in C# *only* support add and remove operations. From the outside, callers can only subscribe to an event and unsubscribe from it. They can't raise it, or find out anything about who's subscribed. Of course, the class can provide a method which will raise the event, but the other class can't access the backing field for the event

I've written this up in more detail in an [article about events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

Comment: So, still a bit confused, but let me restate what I think you are saying and hope I am right: The single line `public event EventHandler Closed;` actually creates two items in the IL?  One that is actually public and one that is private?  The event is public so it can be accessed inside and out side the class.  The "hidden" field (not sure what to call it) is private and can't be called except inside the class?

Comment: @Vaccano: Yes. It declares a field, and an event. It's a bit like an automatically implemented property from C# 3, which creates a property and a field in one go. Personally I wish the field-like event syntax were `public event EventHandler Closed { add; remove; }` - that would have been more obvious, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `Closed(this, e);` is nothing but calling `invoke` on a **private** delegate. This is why only the class can call it.

C# hides all the complexity from you and it creates a private delegate of type event for you (you can use ILDASM to see all this).

This is **private** so it is **not even protected**. This is why it is recommended to use a protected method to raise the event so the subclasses could have access to the event.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is actually calling the event only allowed inside the class? Is that the limitation?

Yes

> If so, is there anyway around it?

Only with the consent (help) from the FauxIdentityForm class. It could have a public OnClosed() method.
An Event is a lot like a property, one of its main purposes is encapsulation and that is what you ran into.

Comment: In the System.Windows.Forms world it's common to expose a protected virtual OnX() method (X is the name of the event) that allows subclasses to control access or call the event directly. You could make this method internal if you wish to call it from other classes